# Как вернуть асинхронную сессию SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, python-3.x, асинхронность, sqlalchemy

У меня есть класс базы данных на Python с асинхронным sessionmaker'ом.

```
class Database(AbstractDatabase):
    def __init__(self):
        self._engine = AsyncEngine(create_engine("postgresql+asyncpg://postgres:postgres@localhost/test", echo=True, future=True))
        self._session_maker = sessionmaker(self._engine, class_=AsyncSession, expire_on_commit=False)
  
    def get_session_maker(self) -> sessionmaker:
        return self._session_maker
```

И у меня есть репозиторий, который получает данные из этой базы.

```
class UsersRepository(AbstractUsersRepository):
    def __init__(self, db: AbstractDatabase):
        self._db = db

    async def get(self, entity_id: UUID) -> User:
        async with self._db.get_session_maker()() as session:
            return await session.get(User, entity_id)
```

Всё нормально работает, но мне не нравится как работает и выглядит метод `get_session_maker`. Можно ли сделать что-то подобное?

```
class Database(AbstractDatabase):
    def __init__(self):
        self._engine = AsyncEngine(create_engine("postgresql+asyncpg://postgres:postgres@localhost/test", echo=True, future=True))
        self._session_maker = sessionmaker(self._engine, class_=AsyncSession, expire_on_commit=False)

    async def get_session(self) -> AsyncSession:
        async with self._session_maker() as session:
            yield session


class UsersRepository(AbstractUsersRepository):
    def __init__(self, db: AbstractDatabase):
        self._db = db

    async def get(self, entity_id: UUID) -> User:
        session = await self._db.get_session()
        return await session.get(User, entity_id)
```

Но я не могу сделать именно этот вариант, так как получаю ошибку `TypeError: object async_generator can't be used in 'await' expression`. И я не очень понимаю почему. Разве это не работает так: `вызывается get` -> `get_session начинает сессию и возвращает ее` -> `get закончил выполнение` -> `вернулся к get_session и закрыл сессию`?

Еще пробовал такой вариант, но он тоже не работает.

```
async def get_session(self) -> AsyncSession:
    session: AsyncSession = self._session_maker()
    try:
        yield session
    except Exception as e:
        await session.rollback()
        print(f"An error occurred: {e}")
    finally:
        await session.close()
```

Comment: get_session асинхронный генератор. Чтобы получить значения из него надо чтобы вызывался метод `__anext__`. Это можно сделать через цикл for или методом asend(None). `session_gen = self._db.get_session(); session = session_gen.asend(None)`. Кстати есть async_sessionmaker

Comment: И не стоит вызывать _session_maker каждый раз при получении сессии. Алхимия используется в рамках какого-то фреймворка или нет? Если в рамках фреймворка то какого? Обычно можно найти примеры как лучше работать с сессиями имено в рамках него.

Comment: @Alpensin использую ахлимию с фаст апи, но не могу просто через Depends получать сессию, лучше через репозиторий

Comment: @Alpensin а почему не стоит вызывать создание сессии? Вы имеете в виду одну сессию на все приложение сделать?

Comment: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/session_basics.html#using-a-sessionmaker
sessionmaker это фабрика классов Session. Служит для конфигурации Session. Можно один раз за проект сконфигурировать Session и потом вызывать по мере необходимости.

Comment: Репозиторий тоже может получать сессию через Depends, как мне видится

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пока что лучшее решение, которое я смог реализовать - это паттерн Unit of Work.

```
class UnitOfWork(AbstractUnitOfWork):
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self._session_maker = SESSION_MAKER

    async def __aenter__(self) -> AbstractUnitOfWork:
        self._session = self._session_maker()
        self.repository1 = Repository1(self._session)
        self.repository2 = Repository2(self._session)
        return self

    async def __aexit__(self, *args) -> None:
        await self._session.rollback()
        await self._session.close()

    async def commit(self) -> None:
        await self._session.commit()
```

Вот файлик с базой.

```
ENGINE = AsyncEngine(create_engine("postgresql+asyncpg://postgres:postgres@localhost/test", echo=True, future=True))
SESSION_MAKER = sessionmaker(ENGINE, class_=AsyncSession, expire_on_commit=False)
```

Плюс такой реализации в том, что я могу обращаться к нескольким репозиториям используя одну сессию, что позволит при ошибке откатить любые изменения, которые должны будут отправиться в базу данных.

Минус, как мне кажется, в том, что в `__aenter__` постоянно пересоздаются репозитории. Поэтому лучше вынести их инициализацию в конструктор без передачи сессии. А когда будет вызываться `__aenter__` можно будет создавать сессию и передавать её в репозитории. Ну а в `__aexit__` после закрытия уже отчищать её в репозиториях.

Работать с `UnitOfWork` можно на слое с сервисами.

```
class StackOverflowService(AbstractStackOverflowService):
    def __init__(self, uow: AbstractUnitOfWork):
        self._uow = uow

    async def do_something(self) -> None:
        async with self._uow as uow:
            await uow.repository1.delete_moderator('Михаил Ребров')
            await uow.repository1.add_user('Михаил Ребров')
            await uow.commit()
```